# Facebook PHP SDK "couldn't connect to host"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to connect to facebook API

```
require_once '/composer/vendor/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxx', // obviously, I've put my app ID in here 
  'app_secret' => 'xxxx', // and my app secret in here
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);
```

To do the following request, which, if I'm right, should give me the number of shares of the URL :

```
$target = 'http://stackoverflow.com';

$node = $fb->get('/?id='.urlencode($target).'&fields=share')->getGraphNode();

$shareCount = $node['share']['share_count'];
```

However, I get the following error :

```
Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' 
with message 'couldn't connect to host' 
in /backend/composer/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:83 

Stack trace: 

#0 /backend/composer/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookClient.php(216): 
Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient->send('https://graph.f...', 'GET', '', Array, 60) 

#1 /backend/composer/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/Facebook.php(504): 
Facebook\FacebookClient->sendRequest(Object(Facebook\FacebookRequest)) 

#2 /backend/composer/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/Facebook.php(377): 
Facebook\Facebook->sendRequest('GET', '/?id=http%3A%2F...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL) 

#3 /backend/the_script_i_am_currently_trying_to_run.php(79): 
Facebook\Facebook->get('/?id=http%3A%2F...') 

#4 {main} thrown in /backend/composer/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 83
```

From what I have read, it could be that I'm not allowed to use cURL on my server, but I'm using it somewhere else and it works, so I don't think the problem comes from here.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Can I up my question... ?

Comment: The SDK is open there for you to debug. Dive into the code you are receiving the errors, get the API call and construct it yourself and try to make it yourself on your server and see if you get the same error, if so, then it's an issue from your server side.